# How to transfer data from magento site to prestashop site?

Tags: php, magento, prestashop-1.6

I was having a website built on magento that I replaced with prestashop. I have the backup files of previous magento website and database of the same. Now, I want to transfer all my data such as products,customer details etc to my prestashop website.
Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please use modules from addons.prestashop.com
or manually by export csv file from magento, changed it to prestashop format
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/CSV+Import+Parameters
and import it